# hook state doesn't update automaticlly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, frontend

I wanted to create pagination in React. All data comes from store. In this code I wanted to implement search engine. On this time I don't have this but i wrote search method which simulate that. OK, it works but - after I click hello, it display only items from category 2 but it display all the time this same pages (in my case 3). If I click 2 times more, it display only 1 page. I added setCountItems and setPages into search becouse this hooks doesn't update automaticlly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { connect} from 'react-redux'
import Article from './article'

const ArticlesContainer = ({ articles }) => {
    const [allItems, setAllItems] = useState(articles.list);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
    const [perSite, setPerSite] = useState(10);
    const [totalItems, setCountItems] = useState(allItems.length);
    const from = (pageNumber - 1) * perSite;
    const to = ((pageNumber - 1) * perSite) + perSite;
    const [pages, setPages] = useState(Math.ceil(totalItems / perSite));

    const handlePageClick = (i) => {
        setPageNumber(i);
    }
    const search = () => {
        setAllItems(allItems.filter(x => x.category=== 2 ));
        setCountItems(allItems.length);
        setPages(Math.ceil(totalItems / perSite));

    }



    const Pagination = ({pages}) => {
        let list = []
        for(let i = 1; i<=pages; i++){
            list.push(<li key={i} onClick={() => handlePageClick(i)}>{i}</li>)
        }
        return list;
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <a onClick={search}>Hello</a>
            {allItems.slice(from, to).map(article =>
                <Article key={article.id} article={article} />
            )}
            <div className="row">
                <ul>
                    <Pagination pages={pages} />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    articles: state.articles
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ArticlesContainer);
```

Where problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be suffering from a common misunderstanding of how State works in React. Updating state, whether via `this.setState` in class or via the "update function" returned by the `useState` hook, doesn't "automagically" change the relevant state value then and there. In class components, that's because of how React's implementation of `setState` works (it's asynchronous), but with Hooks it should be perfectly obvious if you stop to think about it. `setAllItems` is a function, while `allItems` is an array - and they don't have anything directly to do each other. Calling `setAllItems` doesn't change the value of `allItems` - because how could it? `allItems` is just a variable, the only way to give it a new value is to directly mutate or reassign it - clearly calling a separate function, `setAllItems`, with an argument that isn't `allItems`, can't possibly do that.

What it instead does is schedule a rerender of the component - that is, schedules a subsequent call of your function that represents the component - and ensures that the `useState` call corresponding to `allItems` will then return value you set. But this is necessarily a rather indirect process. In particular, `allItems` will have the value you want on the *next* render of your component, but that `search` function won't be called (until the user clicks the button again), so the `setCountItems(allItems.length);` call won't automatically trigger with the "correct" length (the updated length after filtering).

In your case the solution to the problem is very simple. You've overcomplicated your component by introducing far too many state variables, most of which are dependent on each other. Instead of `const [totalItems, setCountItems] = useState(allItems.length);`, just put `const totalItems = allItems.length;` - then this will automatically be recalculated to the correct value on every render. You've no need of a `setCountItems` function, as you know that it will always be equal to `allItems.length` - it doesn't vary independently.

Similarly, you can vastly simplify much else in this component, since the only things which can vary independently, and therefore which needs to be part of state, are the article list and the page number. This is how I would rewrite your component:

```
const perSite = 10;

const ArticlesContainer = ({ articles }) => {
    const [allItems, setAllItems] = useState(articles.list);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

    const totalItems = allItems.length;
    const from = (pageNumber - 1) * perSite;
    const to = ((pageNumber - 1) * perSite) + perSite;
    const pages = Math.ceil(totalItems / perSite);

    const handlePageClick = (i) => {
        setPageNumber(i);
    }
    const search = () => {
        setAllItems(allItems.filter(x => x.category=== 2 ));
    }

    const Pagination = ({pages}) => {
        let list = []
        for(let i = 1; i<=pages; i++){
            list.push(<li key={i} onClick={() => handlePageClick(i)}>{i}</li>)
        }
        return list;
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <a onClick={search}>Hello</a>
            {allItems.slice(from, to).map(article =>
                <Article key={article.id} article={article} />
            )}
            <div className="row">
                <ul>
                    <Pagination pages={pages} />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```